# Is it advisable to have two Form in one VF page?

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, bestpractice

I have a Question , whether having two separate Forms in one VF page is a Best practice.

Please provide your Suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_form.htm):

> A section of a Visualforce page that allows users to enter input and then submit it with an `<apex:commandButton>` or `<apex:commandLink>`. The body of the form determines the data that is displayed and the way it's processed. It's a best practice to use only one `<apex:form>` tag in a page or custom component.

Your **viewstate** size would increase with use of multiple `apex:form`'s, thus affecting the performance of the page. So its recommended to use single form per page.

To avoid multiple `apex:form`, I usually keep it just below `apex:page` level:

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:form>
        <!-- Rest of code -->
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score -3):

It helps to create the page as a form. This tag need to be included in the page to accept input from the users. It's a best practice to have only one < apex:form > tag in a page instead of including it many times

Also,

> In Visualforce you can do it like in a normal html page, that is
>   using javascript function. But the "problem" in visualforce is that
>   element ids are generated "on-the-fly" so you can not acces your form
>   element just like this document.form1.submit. I would do it with
>   jQuery because it has very powerfull selectors:

Comment: Wondering on what does `apex:form` has to do with jQuery

Comment: You can access the form without jQuery also. VF Page provide  `$Component` global variable to access these dynamically generated ids.